# How to represent a char array to a single string in c

Tags: c

I just start to learn the c language, and now I have some questions about the string in c, which is a char array. And I notice I can convert a string of hex to decimal with function strtol(), but I saw the examples online, they are all using something like below, it works without any problem.

```
char str[]="a24e38154c";

long n = strtol(str,NULL,16);

printf("%ld",n);</i>
```

I edited my code base on your help.

```
char arr[100];

char *ptr;

memset(arr,0x00,strlen(arr));

ptr = arr;

arr[0] = 0xa2;

arr[1] = 0x4e;
```

...there are 8 elements in total

```
for( int i = 0;i<8;i++){

ptr+=sprintf(ptr,"%02x",arr[i]);

}

printf("%s",arr);
```

then the output is 0x000ffffffa24e...
what does it mean? And where are those zeros and fs coming from?

Thank you

Comment: `strlen(arr)` is not a good idea for an uninitialized array. Did you mean `sizeof`?

Comment: Is `'a2'` supposed to be `'\a2'`?

Comment: `str = arr;` -> `ptr = arr`?

Comment: try enclosing your `%s` in single quotes or something, the `%s` format prints every element of a char array as `%c` until it reaches 0x00 the `nul` byte.

Comment: Doesn't your compiler warn you about `'a2'`?

Comment: what I'm thinking is when I write arr[0]='a2', will arr become a double array? I'm not sure I can insert 2 characters in one char array element.

Comment: yes `'a2'` should be `0xa2` well spotted

Comment: `'a2'` is a single (implementation defined) integer, not two characters.

Comment: but why the compiler does not have any warning, when I trying to assign a 4bytes 'a2' to a char?

Comment: because from the original code, the a2 is came form a char array, which I still don't understand, I print a2 out by "%02x".

Comment: Are you compiling with `-Wall`?

Comment: "string in c, which is a char array": Correction, a string is a null-terminated char array. A literal string implicitly includes a null-terminator.

Comment: how can I print the arr as a string with "%s" in C? You have written the correct answer, printf("%s", arr); I think you feel unhappy with the value that is printed.

Comment: I edited the code just now, and the output made me more confused.

Comment: `char[]str="a24e38154c";` ?? What does your compiler say about that? Perhaps `char str[] = "a24e38154c";`?

Comment: yeah, my bad I typed wrong, thanks

Comment: regarding: `memset(arr,0x00,strlen(arr));`  the array `arr[]` has not been set to any specific values, and the function: `strlen()` will keep going through memory until it encounters a NUL byte.  The chances are very good that a NUL byte will not be encountered in the confines of the array.  The result is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event

Comment: please don;t retype your code, rather, use a copy and paste to put the code into the question.  For us to really help you, please post a [mcve] that shows the problem, include the inputs and the outputs. and what is wrong with the outputs

Comment: without ptr+=, you can only store the last element in the array.

Comment: @codeN,  I realized that after looking at the code snippets some more, so I had erased the comment

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing strings and numbers and long/int.  Strings are sequences of characters in memory.  Numbers are an abstract concept that can be represented in many ways.  `long` and `int` are numeric data types in C that represent numbers.

So the function `strtol` converts a number represented as a string of digits in some base ("hex" or "decimal" or "octal" are all possible) into the `long` representation of that number.  It does not convert hex to decimal (or do any kind of "base" conversion), though it can be used as half of a function that does.

When you use `printf("%ld"` it converts a number in the `long` representation into a decimal string representation and prints that on stdout (usually your terminal window).  This is necessary to display anything related to a number, as terminals cannot display numbers, only characters.

Now all the above distinctions between numbers and representations of numbers may seem obscure, but it is very important -- crucially important in understanding how to write and understand programs written in C.

Answer (score 0):

The type of arr should be unsigned char